# Why there is no effect of restrict pointer

Tags: c, pointers, restrict-qualifier

I can't see any difference of code by gcc for restrict pointers.

**file1**

```
void test (int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
  while (*a)
  {
    *c++ = *a++ + *b++; 
  }
}
```

**file2**

```
void test (int *restrict a, int *restrict b, int *restrict c)
{
  while (*a)
  {
    *c++ = *a++ + *b++;
  }
}
```

compile with

```
  gcc -S -std=c99 -masm=intel file1.c
  gcc -S -std=c99 -masm=intel file2.c
```

**file1.s** and **file2.s** both are same, except the `.file` line, which tells the filename:

```
    .file   "file1.c"
    .text
    .globl  test
    .type   test, @function
test:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %edx
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, (%rax)
    addq    $4, -24(%rbp)
    addq    $4, -8(%rbp)
    addq    $4, -16(%rbp)
.L2:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L3
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   test, .-test
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Both of these code read from the memory and then assign the memory location pointed to by `a` to `b`. Where i expected the `restrict` version will not re-read the addresses of `a` and `b`, and the addresses of `a` and `b` will be incremented in-register and at the end written to memory.

Is there anything wrong i am doing? Or is the selection of the example okay?

I have tried with different switches `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Ofast`, and `-fstrict-aliasing`  with the same identical results for both of the files.

*Note:* gcc --version = gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)

**EDIT** Code changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the following expression:

```
    *c++ = *a++ + *b++;
```

pretty much needs to dereference all the pointers in each loop iteration anyway, since the pointers change in each iteration.  There's no benefit to using `restrict`.

Try changing the line inside the loop to:

```
    *c++ = *a++ + *b;
```

(you may need to also enable optimizations such as `-O2`).

You'll see that in the `restrict` case it loads `*b` into a register once, while in the case without restrict it needs to load through the pointer in each loop iteration because it doesn't know whether or not `c` ever aliases `b`.

Answer (score 7):

You are only reading through one of the pointers, so `restrict` doesn't matter.

See [this example](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html) where it does matter because the pointers may alias the same data, and the data are written and read through both pointers.

Comment: I have changed the code, can you please have a look at the new one?

Comment: The new version does not re-read any memory in either case, so again, restrict has no effect. I.e., every `int` is read once. It the the data pointed to by the pointer, not the pointer itself that is at issue with `restrict`.